# Replace title in react native Navigator's navigationBar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigator

I load remote data after pushing a route into the Navigator and want to update the navigation bar title once the data has loaded.

I can call `this.props.navigator.replace({ component: MyComponent, title: 'Updated Title' })` but that also triggers a re-mount and re-render of the entire scene.

Is there any way to update the Navigator's navigationBar display without updating a route?

Comment: Why not use state variable in the  title and then setState when you want to change the title.

Comment: There is not an API to reference the title view from the navigator. I guess I could pass in a title object then assign it to the props of the component. Is that what you're thinking?

Comment: Yes. Kind of. <Navigator navigationBar={<Text> {this.state. title} </Text>} />

Answer (score 0):

Check out this GitHub issue: [[Navigator] Binding the navigation bar with the underlying scene](http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2615)

One commenter suggested using events. You can emit an event from any Component with the new title as an argument. Your navbar title Component can listen for these events and update itself as it receives them.

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647114/4621566) demonstrates how to use the event syntax.